# Lines at infinity in the complex projective plane

Tags: complex-numbers, projective-space

I have been learning about complex projective spaces and my professor was saying something about there being three complex projective lines at the points of infinity in a $\Bbb C \Bbb P _2$ (ie a complex projective plane). I don't really understand this. If anyone could explain this or perhaps point me towards some references for me to read, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *three projective lines at the points of infinity* . what does that mean?  Viewing a projective plane as a completion of an affine plane, there should be just one line made up entirely of ideal points.

Comment: From my understanding, we have three charts for CP2 and we have three points at infinity (one for each chart). Somehow we can relate CP1 to infinity, ie) we would get 3 lines at infinity.

Comment: well.. there are three ideal points... there are infinitely many ideal points.  You asked first about three *lines*.  Surely there is some missing context here. The idea of a chart is orthogonal to the projective plane and its lines.

Comment: The line at infinite *is* related to CP1... it is a copy of CP1. But it is not "three lines" as far as I can tell.

Comment: If we have CP2 and its coordinates are (x,y,z) then the three charts are (x,y,1) , (x,1,z) and (1,y,z) and the points at infinity are (0,0,1), (0,1,0), (1,0,0). Is there any way to relate CP1 (ie coordinates (x,y)) to any these points at infinity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If we have CP2 and its coordinates are (x,y,z) then the three charts are (x,y,1) , (x,1,z) and (1,y,z) and the points at infinity are (0,0,1), (0,1,0), (1,0,0). Is there any way to relate CP1 (ie coordinates (x,y)) to any these points at infinity?

The corresponding lines at infinity, given these choices of affine planes within the complex plane, would be $\{((x,y,0)\mid x,y\in \mathbb C\}$, $\{((x,0,z)\mid x,z\in \mathbb C\}$ and $\{((0,y,z)\mid y,z\in \mathbb C\}$ respectively.

The relationship with the points you've given (respectively) is that they are orthogonal with respect to the inner product. Said another way, the $1$-d subspace represented by each of those points has a normal plane complement in $\mathbb C^3$, which when collapsed into $\mathbb{CP}^2$ is a line (the line of points at infinity.

To me, the points you gave are the origin of the chosen affine plane, not some point on the corresponding line at infinity.